# How to solve buggy line-height on input fields?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do you give an input field, with fixed height, a cross-browser vertical alignment of the text it holds?

As of now, it seems `line-height` is my best option. However, on a webkit browser like Chrome or Safari, the cursor jumps to a top-alignment when copy/pasting.

I've noticed Wordpress seems to have a solution for this, with their [wp-login form](http://wordpress.org/wp-login/).

Does anybody know how Wordpress manages to do this?

CSS

```
input {
    width: 240px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Please post an example of the code you;re referring to, and when possible a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: Updated. It's just simple css. But it seems like a webkit bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use a set line-height for the whole document, **`vertical-align: middle`** for both labels and inputs and **`padding`**.
I also redefine `font` (family and size) for input, the same as for `label` because browsers already have their default like 13.3px...
Finally `border: 1px solid someColor` will help for browsers with 1 more px or an inset.

No `height`.

Then comes Chrome and its select. Oh `@*$£#`... [isellsoap forms.css](http://isellsoap.github.io/forms.css/) nailed it, by removing and redefining everything, except it uses height and not padding (in my opinion it's less versatile)

Comment: Not setting `height` indeed solves this! I should've come up with this myself.. Still weird though. I found a Issue thread about it on some Chromium forum, which is still not solved.

Comment: Many CSS things related to forms let the UA style them whatever they want. Not necessarily a bad thing (select on iPhone is more usable as is) but it leads to bug reports closed as WONTFIX because no standard has defined anything... Part frustrating, part understandable ;)