# HTML/CSS If you set height to input, line-height stops working

Tags: html, css

Input work fine with padding. For prevent troubles with different border-width, rewrite to set height, and remove vertical padding. In result text align and line-height is broken. How to fix text align in input, and save easy height set?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hlvz.png)

[Link to reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cdn-9oqgr?file=/index.html)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      }
      .container {
        padding: 40px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 20px;
      }
      input {
        display: block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid darkgray;
        min-width: 180px;
        outline: none !important; // for example
      }
      #input1 {
        padding: 7px 12px;
      }
      #input2 {
        height: 40px;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <input value="Some value" type="text" id="input1" />
      <input value="Some value" type="text" id="input2" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve buggy line-height on input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603197/how-to-solve-buggy-line-height-on-input-fields)

Comment: @A.Meshu for my position **"Not setting height"** , is not answer. It would be nice to have some links to chrome issue, or blog post with describe - why it's dont work